# C# OAuth 1.0 How to get access_token without opening browser for dropbox authorization (Desktop app)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oauth, dropbox

I develop Desktop app dropbox client, i want to authorize my app and get ability go perform api requests, but i dont want to show to user browser window, is any way to authorize user without browser and get access_token in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: There is no supported way to do this with the OAuth flows that are implemented by Dropbox.

The idea of these flows is that the user only has to hand over his password directly on the (trusted) providers web site, which is just not possible without a browser/web view.

Comment: I know it's been 8 years now, but this now could be done. The problem is that : It's not acceptable in Dropbox to use something like Webbrowser Control to get Access Token (doable though).